# How to configure portable WiFi router in Xiaomi mi 4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I hv miui 6 version of rom. How can I configure my connected users like allow or block them etc that r connected to my hotspot which I created on my mi4.... Plz help

Answer (score 0):

You can block them by their mobile's MAC(Physical) address.
But the better way is to change your Wi-fi hotspot password if you do not want to share your internet connection with others.

Comment: Can you elaborate the first part?